# Why is "goto-line" in Emacs for interactive use only?

Tags: emacs, elisp

What problem can happen if the `goto-line` function is used in a non-interactive elisp program? Its docstring gives a warning saying that:

> This function is usually the wrong thing to use in a Lisp program.
>   What you probably want instead is something like:
>
> ```
> (goto-char (point-min)) (forward-line (1- N))
> ```

Moreover, when I try to `byte-compile-file` my init file including `goto-line`, I get a unpleasant warning like this once again:

```
.emacs:170:19:Warning: `goto-line' used from Lisp code
That command is designed for interactive use only
```

Is using `goto-line` in a non-interactive program really so dangerous? Relatedly, why is the suggested `forward-line` solution preferable?

Comment: Not sure how goto-line would work not interactively, it goes to a line in the current buffer

Comment: @JonLin You can find an example that non-interactively uses `goto-line` at [EmacsWiki:AUCTeX](http://emacswiki.org/emacs/AUCTeX#toc20):`th-evince-sync`.

Comment: event_jr has answered your question as posed, but still *why* are you trying to do this?  There may be a better way to accomplish what you really want.  Also, I would point out that if the buffer has been narrowed going to a certain line probably isn't going to do what you think it is.

Comment: @scottfrazer At first sight, because of its name, the `goto-line` statement appeared to be a more intuitive (and compact) way to go to the _n_-th line than the `forward-line` idiom. Moreover, I came across some programs on the Internet that were using `goto-line` non-interactively. Now I understand that `goto-line` can have some side-effects that a developer might not expect. As for narrowing, `forward-line` is also resctricted to the accessible portion of a buffer.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Firstly, this prevents Elisp programmers from fall into bad habits -- writing
inefficient code in a line-number centric way.  i.e. instead of using
`(forward-line 1)` calculating the current line number, incrementing, and using
`goto-line`.

From [this](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/help-gnu-emacs/2004-02/msg00642.html) mailing list article:

> In a nutshell, the reason why goto-line should not be a frequently
>   used command is that normally there's no reason to want to get to line
>   number N unless you have a program that told you there's something
>   interesting on that line.

Secondly, goto-line manipulates the user's environment in addition to moving
the point (i.e. `push-mark`).  For non-interactive use, this may not be what
you want.  On the other hand if having considered all this, you believe
goto-line is exactly what you need, then just call it like this:

```
(defun foo ()
  (interactive)
  (with-no-warnings
    (goto-line N)))
```

And you won't get any compiler warnings.

Comment: "normally there's no reason to want to get to line number N unless you have a program that told you there's something interesting on that line" — what if your program (or elisp code) has computed that there _is_ indeed something interesting on that line? Then is the recommendation to subtract current line from that line, and use forward-line instead? (Easy, but just  making sure.)

Comment: I prefer to use `funcall-interactively` to suppress that particular compiler warning, as it would not swallow other potential warnings. I.e. `(funcall-interactively #'goto-line N)`

Answer (score 6):

in addition to what was said:

"goto-line" finally recurs onto "(forward-line (1- line)",  which in effect does the work. All other of the 43 lines of "goto-line" command body deal with interactive use. For example considering a possibly universal argument.

When writing a program resp. when running it, your computer is in another state than following an interactive call. Thus you should address this state by using "forward-line" straight on.

Comment: The `(interactive arg-descriptor)` part that deals with interactive use looks like being skipped when `goto-line` is called from Lisp programs. From [the reference manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Using-Interactive.html#index-interactive-1253), "A command may be called from Lisp programs like any other function, but then the caller supplies the arguments and _arg-descriptor_ has no effect."

Comment: @dkim Also code beyond calculation of the argument deals with interactive use: there is still push-mark, switch-to-buffer and the like.